# Login still directs even if incorrect credential with AngularJS and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs

The PHP code needs to fetch data from the table, decode it as JSON and then send it to AngularJS.

Angular JS redirects if the login credentials are correct.

However even if the credentials are incorrect, the user is still redirected (true statement always passes).

**PHP Code:**

```
 <?php
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

    $username = $data->username;
    $password = $data->password;

     /*
   * Collect all Details from Angular HTTP Request.
   */ require_once("connection.php");
    //must read from table
    $connection = connectToMySQL();
    //complete from here

    $query = "SELECT count(*) FROM tbl_admin WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection ,$query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    $count = $row[0];

    if($count == 1)
    {
        echo true;
    }
    else 
    {
        echo false;
    }

?>
```

**AngularJS Controller:**

```
app.controller('loginCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $location) {
   /*
    * This method will be called on click event of button.
    * Here we will read the email and password value and call our PHP file.
    */
    $scope.checkCredentials = function (credentials) {
        $http.post('model/getAdmin.php',credentials).success(function(data){
            console.log("true");
            $location.path("/memberList");
      })
      .error(function(err){
          $log.error(err);
          console.log("false");
      });
    }
});
```

HTML Form Code

```
<form class="form-group" id="customForms" ng-controller="loginCtrl">
        <label> Username </label> 
        <input id="customFormsInput" class="form-control" ng-model="credentials.username" type="text" placeholder="Username goes here" required/>
        <br> 
        <label> Password </label>
        <input id="customFormsInput" class="form-control" ng-model="credentials.password" type="password" placeholder="Password goes here" required/>
        <br> <br>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ng-click="checkCredentials(credentials)"> Submit </button>
        <br>
            {{responseMessage}}
            <!-- Shows message depending on login type -->
    </form>
```

Comment: Try `console.log(data)` and see the servers response.

Comment: I have changed the echo from the php side, and now The `console.log(data)` showed me that from the PHP side, the validation is good. (Returns PHP True, and PHP False). However the controlling is only going through the true statement only.

Comment: `$http.post` resolves even if the server responds with `false`. Instead of that, the server could response with some information in JSON, such that your application knows WHY the checking for credentials failed.

Comment: In other words: You need to add a check in your success-function. Like: `.success(function(data) { if (data === "PHP True") { $location.path ...`

Comment: Works thanks!!! @iWörk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `if-else` condition to your `success` callback since you are always sending 200 response even if you are sending `false` from your PHP code:

```
$scope.checkCredentials = function (credentials) {
  $http.post('model/getAdmin.php',credentials).success(function(data){
        console.log("true", data);
        if (data == true) {    // Or in whatever form you are receiving true/false
            $location.path("/memberList");
        } else {
            $log.error(err);
            console.log("false");
        }
  })
}
```

If you want to make your older code working i.e. with `success` & `error` callbacks in Angular then you need to send a non-200 response code along with `false` from your PHP code like:

```
if($count == 1)
{
    echo true;
}
else 
{
    http_response_code(406);       // not acceptable response code
    echo false;
}
```

(The second solution is recommended)

I've never worked on PHP, so make sure `http_response_code(406);` is written correct.